# Jenkins sonar quality gates issue

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have a Jenkins jobs for sonar analysis. When I try to add build step for Quality Gates (in order to mark a failure if new bugs), I get this error:

```
JSONObject["projectKey"] not found.
```

Can someone help?

Comment: @Jack, Please let know which version of Jenkins, SonarQube you are choosing and also post the screen shot indicating the error stack trace appearing on Jenkins UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quality gates build step can only come under **POST build actions**.

So try to add post build action of Quality Gates. And make sure you are giving a project key.

Project Key can be taken note of from sonar server console.

This should solve the error.